# How to solve log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [aiAppender] of type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, log4net, log4net-appender

I have .net core 3.1 console application which is referring to a .net class library project.

I am getting the below exception.

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [aiAppender] of type
> [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender,
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender]. Reported error
> follows. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file
> specified. File name: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    at
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark,
> ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack
> keepalive)    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name,
> Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
> AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
> typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark&
> stackMark)    at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
> log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly,
> String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
> log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
> log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement
> appenderElement)
>
> log4net:ERROR Appender named [aiAppender] not found.

**App.config:**

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

to solve this issue I tried to add a package from NuGet package manager `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender`, but I am getting the below error while adding this package.

> Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at
> 'http://fxnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'
> with following message : The specified path, file name, or both are
> too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
> characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
> qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
> directory name must be less than 248 characters.

But my project path is just `J:\fx-core`

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'll try your solution and hopefully it works for me as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added `log4net` package to both the projects and error is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling log4net nuget package, if that doesn't help check in folder directory-bin-Debug if you are missing log4net and log4net.dll files.

Comment: this is a repeat of another answer